# How can we change the default html file generated by doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen, eclipse-cdt, doxygen-wizard

I am using doxygen and doxywizard for documentation C code.

How to rename the index.html file through configuring doxygen or doxywizard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change this from configuration. Main page is always `index.html`. And you cannot really rename it afterwards because of all cross-references that point to the main page.

But you can make doxygen output generated files to a specific folder using [`HTML_OUTPUT`](http://www.doxygen.nln/manual/config.html#cfg_html_output) configuration option.